# Install jdk in many windows servers using chocolatey

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

We are starting a new project where I have to install JDK and JRE into Windows 2008R2 servers. I want to use Chocolatey for this. As a beginner could any of you suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the Chocolatey Website, you will find packages for both the JDK and JRE.  Here are the relevant links:

- [Search Chocolatey.org for JRE Packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=id%3Ajre)
- [Search Chocolatey.org for JDK Packages](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=id%3Ajdk)

**NOTE:** Here I am using the ability to query only the Package ID using the `id:` notation.

You will see that a number of packages are returned for each search, and especially for the JDK, this is because there are different versions available.  Only you will know which version you want though.

After you have identified if a package exists that suits your needs you can go ahead and install it.  The instructions on how to do this are on the package page itself, for example [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jdk), assuming that you are happy to install the latest JDK.

```
choco install jdk
```

If there is not a package that exactly fits what you are looking for, you might have to implement your own package.  The creation of a package, and what is required is too long to include within this answer, but I would encourage you to read the extensive documentation that we have available [here.](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CreatePackages)

Comment: Thanks Gary for the resolution. I have installed JDK and JRE into my machines using chocolety. In case If I need to install JDK and JRE into several 100 Windows server 2008R at a time what is the exact procedure..

Comment: @KalyanBhave Chocolatey does not give any mechanism, out of the box, to control the installations on multiple PC's.  You would need to look to another system, perhaps Puppet or Chef, to control the deployment of the configuration (in this case, what applications to install) onto the hundreds of machines that you are using.

Comment: I was given a task of installing basic applications like JDK,JRE,PDI,TOMCAT etc.. in 100+ Windows Servers 2008 R2. As these all installations are manual so I am looking for alternate solution.

Comment: There are many solutions out there, but out of the box, Chocolatey alone is not going to provide you with what you are looking for.  You would need to combine Chocolatey with something else in order to scale to that number of machines.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this type of problem. As I am unable to check out this in Search engines.

Comment: @KalyanBhave I have already made a number of recommendations, i.e. Puppet and or Chef.  There are others as well like Ansible and SCCM.